# Bouncy castle - implementation of encryption and decryption XML file?

Tags: android, bouncycastle

do you know any links with simple implementations of encryption and decryption XML files? I am going to use it in Android, and  so far I haven't found any usefull link.

Thanks

Comment: Do you indeed mean **encryption**, or do you mean **encoding** ? The first is basically making it unreadable for people without the key, the second is actually making an XML file, parsing it, etc etc... The second is a more common situation, that's why I ask :)

Comment: I ment that what I was asking for, encryption = encryption - I want to check if the file has the same signature and if so, download it an use further

Comment: No offence meant ofcourse, just checking. It's a common mistake so i'd thought i'd ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use The Legion of the Bouncy Castle directly in Android. You use the `javax.crypto` APIs, similar to other Java environments. [Here is a link to some sample code](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesFile.html) for encrypting and decrypting files with `javax.crypto`.

If you have further questions on `javax.crypto`, I recommend tagging your questions with `java` instead of, or in addition to, `android`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked on that source code, but I don't know, where can I add my key.keystore, which contains my keys for encryption and decryption...

Comment: @Hmyzak: Then I suggest you ask a new SO question about using a keystore with `javax.crypto`, and add the `java` tag to that question.

Comment: The Android JCE provider is bouncycastle. But you are saying the BC lightweight API is unavailable in Android?

Comment: @GregS: The native BC API is not exposed as part of the Android SDK.